# Dynamically changing VideoJs' flash fallback source?

Tags: flash, video, html, fallback

I'm using [VideoJs](http://videojs.com/) to handle my HTML5 video needs, using a single M4V. I needed a playlist, and I'm able to change it's source easily using JS (in my case, jQuery).

However, I'm not able to pass these changes along to the flash fallback (which is achieved via an object including [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/)).

Any ideas on how one might be able to dynamically change flowplayer's flashvars, and reload the object?

Comment: Don't assume that people know which 3rd party products you're referring to.  You should include links for [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/), and [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/).  If nothing else, it saves people the trouble of going to google them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [flowplayer's "PlayList plugin"](http://flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/playlist.html) might do the trick.